# macOS pf asymmetric routing through VLANs

Tags: osx, vlan, pf

I have a VLAN interface `vlan0` that has a tag of 444 that has an IP of `172.16.16.16`

The VLAN goes through the physical `en0` interface.

I have another interface `mine0` that's local just to the computer. The internal IP is assigned `192.168.168.168`

I'm attempting to use `binat` rules to do a 1:1 NAT between `vlan0` and `mine0`

My `pf.conf`:

```
binat on vlan0 from 172.16.16.16 to any -> 192.168.168.168
```

After setting up the pf rules I attempt to SSH using the `172.16.16.16` address.

My output from `tcpdump host 10.10.10.10`:

```
22:06:41.397177 IP 10.10.10.10.34755 > 172.16.16.16.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1984840961, win 26883, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4060403773 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:06:41.397258 IP 192.168.168.168.ssh > 10.10.10.10.34755: Flags [S.], seq 2419525153, ack 1984840962, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 824423934 ecr 4060403773,sackOK,eol], length 0
22:06:42.400361 IP 192.168.168.168.ssh > 10.10.10.10.34755: Flags [S.], seq 2419525153, ack 1984840962, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 824424934 ecr 4060403773,sackOK,eol], length 0
22:06:42.425900 IP 10.10.10.10.34755 > 172.16.16.16.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1984840961, win 26883, options [mss 8861,sackOK,TS val 4060404802 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:06:42.425994 IP 192.168.168.168.ssh > 10.10.10.10.34755: Flags [S.], seq 2419525153, ack 1984840962, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 824424958 ecr 4060404802,sackOK,eol], length 0
22:06:44.405921 IP 192.168.168.168.ssh > 10.10.10.10.34755: Flags [S.], seq 2419525153, ack 1984840962, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 824426935 ecr 4060404802,sackOK,eol], length 0
22:06:44.441985 IP 10.10.10.10.34755 > 172.16.16.16.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1984840961, win 26883, options [mss 8861,sackOK,TS val 4060406818 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:06:44.442072 IP 192.168.168.168.ssh > 10.10.10.10.34755: Flags [S.], seq 2419525153, ack 1984840962, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 824426971 ecr 4060406818,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Each of the SYN packets (`Flags [S]`) come in over the `vlan0` interface.

However each of the SYN ACK packets (`Flags [S.]`) go over the `en0` interface.

What do I need to change in order to have the packets going out use `vlan0`?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a router or firewall between you and the other computer this:

> SYN    S   Syn packet, is a session establishment request.

This request may not even get to its destination and even if it does you may not get a response. The state information may not be there if the security on one side is tighter than the other.

As sited: [Cisco Web Services News:](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pf-strange-problem-with-linux-debian-ubuntu-clients-only.19444/)


Try this:

Set the variables to the interfaces you need them to be.

```
# Static 1:1 NAT for the internal WWW servers
binat on $ext_if from $www1_int to any -> $www1_ext
binat on $ext_if from $www2_int to any -> $www2_ext
```

Information found here: [FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pf-strange-problem-with-linux-debian-ubuntu-clients-only.19444/)

Comment: Added some info I found.